# HSQLDB - updatable statements don't work with "SELECT TOP" or "ORDER BY"

Tags: hsqldb

I'm using HSQLDB and preparedStatements just fine, but if I include either "SELECT TOP" or "ORDER BY" in my SQL statement, when I call updateBoolean (or UpdateInt, etc), I hit an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: attempt to assign to non-updatable column
```

This sample code works fine:

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareUpdatable(
    "SELECT " + MyTable.COL_ID + ", " +
        MyTable.COL_READ +
        " FROM " + MyTable.NAME +
        " WHERE " + MyTable.COL_LOCAL +
        " =? AND " + MyTable.COL_REMOTE +
        " =?",
    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

preparedStatement.setString(1, localAddress);
preparedStatement.setString(2, remoteAddress);

ResultSet rs = connection.query(preparedStatement);

if (rs.next())
{
    rs.updateBoolean(MyTable.COL_READ, isRead);
    rs.updateRow();
}
```

I get the exception if I change "SELECT" to "SELECT TOP".  Or if I append this to the SQL statement:

```
" ORDER BY " + MyTable.COL_RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP + " DESC"
```

Thanks for any help.

NickB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An updatable SELECT statement cannot have `TOP n`, `LIMIT` or `ORDER BY`. This restriction is imposed by the SQL standard. Your SELECT becomes not-updatable when you add one of those keywords.

It is possible to use a subquery in a WITH clause with the above keywords and the SELECT is updatable.

```
CREATE TABLE t (a int, b int, PRIMARY KEY(a));

WITH SUBQ(COL) AS (SELECT TOP 1 a FROM t) 
  SELECT * FROM t WHERE a IN (SELECT * FROM SUBQ)
```